# How to break out of recursion? C Programming

Tags: c, recursion

I have a trenary tree every node got id and name
how can I return true when root->id=id
and break the recursion

```
BOOLEAN isIdUsed(Trin_Ari *root,int idNumber) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return FALSE;
    if (root->id==idNumber)
        return TRUE;
    isIdUsed(root->left,idNumber);
    isIdUsed(root->middle,idNumber);
    isIdUsed(root->right,idNumber);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: You're returning a boolean. Why not check it when you call the function recursively? When it's TRUE,  you're done (you return TRUE if a recursive call returns TRUE). Currently, you still return FALSE even if a recursive call to `isIdUsed` returns TRUE.

Comment: While all the answers below fix your bug (which @lurker pointed out), please note that they also change the behavior you had by bailing out once one of the paths returned TRUE. This is a reasonable optimization, but it doesn't always call all 3 recursive calls, and if they had other side effect that would break program behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're ignoring the return values from the recursive calls to `isIdUsed`. Once you encounter a `TRUE` there,  you need to propagate it upwards:

```c
BOOLEAN isIdUsed(Trin_Ari *root,int idNumber) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return FALSE;
    if (root->id==idNumber)
        return TRUE;
    if (isIdUsed(root->left,idNumber))
        return TRUE;
    if (isIdUsed(root->middle,idNumber))
        return TRUE;
    if (isIdUsed(root->right,idNumber))
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> how can i return true when root->id=id and break the recursion

You can break the recursion as you mentioned, just check if the root ID is the idNumber and then return false. You can just return the three checks at the end such as:

```
BOOLEAN isIdUsed(Trin_Ari *root,int idNumber) {
if (root==NULL)
    return FALSE;
if (root->id==idNumber)
    return TRUE;
return isIdUsed(root->left,idNumber) || isIdUsed(root->middle,idNumber) || isIdUsed(root->right,idNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never backpropagate the results...

```c
BOOLEAN isIdUsed(Trin_Ari *root,int idNumber) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return FALSE;
    if (root->id==idNumber)
        return TRUE;

    if (isIdUsed(root->left,idNumber))
        return TRUE;
    if (isIdUsed(root->middle,idNumber))
        return TRUE;
    if (isIdUsed(root->right,idNumber))
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't take the result of the sub recursions into account. You need to get their returned value to decide if you break the recursion.

```
BOOLEAN isIdUsed(Trin_Ari *root,int idNumber) {
if (root==NULL)
    return FALSE;

if (root->id==idNumber)
    return TRUE;

if (isIdUsed(root->left,idNumber))
    return TRUE;

if (isIdUsed(root->middle,idNumber))
    return TRUE;

if (isIdUsed(root->right,idNumber))
    return TRUE;

return FALSE;
```

}